# how to recovery the records from the ldf file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, recovery, ldf

Yesterday,my database file is broken,and i can't connect it.I just have the backup file before.
Now,the database files can not be attached.

### 标题: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

附加数据库 对于 服务器“BAUER”失败。  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

有关帮助信息，请单击: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.3000.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).121019-1322+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=附加数据库+Server&LinkId=20476

---

其他信息:

执行 Transact-SQL 语句或批处理时发生了异常。 (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

无法在数据库“sq_mikrotiknet”(数据库 ID 为 7)的分配单元 72057594042449920，页 (1:204) 上重做事务 ID (0:10603) 的日志记录 (82:739:2)。页: LSN = (82:342:2)，分配单元 = 72057594042449920，类型 = 1。日志: OpCode = 6，上下文 2，PrevPageLSN: (82:360:2)。请从数据库备份还原该数据库，或者修复它。
在重做数据库 'sq_mikrotiknet' 的日志中记录的操作时，日志记录 ID (82:739:2) 出错。通常，特定故障以前会在 Windows 事件日志服务中记录为错误。请利用完整备份还原数据库，或者修复该数据库。
无法打开新数据库 'sq_mikrotiknet'。CREATE DATABASE 中止。 (Microsoft SQL Server，错误: 3456)

有关帮助信息，请单击: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3456&LinkId=20476

---

按钮:

### 确定

Comment: Is there any way you can translate that? I believe the number of people who could help you would increase drastically if we could read (Japanese I'm assuming)

Comment: Sorry,It's not Japanese,it's Chinese.I will install the English version database on the Windows Azure today,and paste the message.Thanks.

Comment: Attach database failed for Server 'AZUREEXAMPLE'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4319.0+((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).140617-1840+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Comment: Could not redo log record (82:739:2), for transaction ID (0:10603), on page (1:204), database 'sq_mikrotiknet' (db ID 5). Page: LSN = (82:342:2), type = 1. Log: OpCode = 6, context 2, PrevPageLSN: (82:360:2). Restore from a backup of the database, or repair the database.During redoing of a logged operation in database 'sq_mikrotiknet', an error occurred at log record ID (82:739:2).

Comment: Typically, the specific failure is previously logged as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database from a full backup, or repair the database.Could not open new database 'sq_mikrotiknet'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Error: 3456)